# Is there a deformation retract from $\Bbb{S}^1$ to $\Bbb{S}^1\lor \Bbb{S}^1$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, deformation-theory, retraction

I am solving the following exercise.

> Show that there is no deformation retract $r:X\rightarrow A$ where $X=\bar{\Bbb{B}^2}\lor\bar{\Bbb{B}^2}$ and $A=\Bbb{S}^1\lor\Bbb{S}^1$.

As I understand this, if we have a deformation retract, then two spaces are homotopy equivalent and have the same fundamental group right?

But looking at the prove of this exercise given by our TA, I think something went wrong, this is the solution.

[image]

He stated that $S^1$ is a retract of $\Bbb{S}^1\lor\Bbb{S}^1$ but if he mans $\Bbb{S}^1$ then I don't think this is true since we don't have the same fundamental group. But another $S^1$ wasn't defined. So I'm a bit confused.

Would be nice if someone can take a look and explain me where the mistake is.

**Additional question** Is this an iff statement when we say that if X is a deformation retract of Y, and $\Pi(X)=\Pi(Y)$?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered the difference between retract and *deformation* retract?

Comment: yes but I think that here we can't speak about retract, since this because only if it is a deformation retract we can say that they are homotopy equivalent and thus have the fundamental group if I remember correclty, if it is a retract, we can't say something about the fundamental groups. So in my opinion this is only an abuse of notation isn't it?

Comment: The claim is not that there is an isomorphism (which would be false, as you seem to know), but only that there is a surjection. The point is that a retraction induces a surjection on fundamental groups. Is this the fact you're missing?

Comment: sorry I think I didn't really got it. So they really mean retraction and not deformation retract and made an abuse of notation? So maybe you can explain me again the difference between retraction and deformation retraction and what follows from the two I think I messed something up

Comment: Where do you think there is an abuse of notation?

Comment: that they wrote retract instead of deformation retract

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133720/discussion-between-aprozz-and-thorgott).

Comment: No, they *do* mean retract wherever it is written. In fact, the argument they use shows not only that there is no deformation retraction $X\rightarrow A$, but that there is no retraction $X\rightarrow A$ at all. So we really don't need to think about deformation retractions at all.

Comment: I thought that maybe we can shortly discuss the difference between those two in chat if you don't mind?